# How do I limit NSTextView to 2 lines?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview, nsmutableattributedstring, nsparagraphstyle

I'm trying to specify the number of lines for NSTextView. My designer is requesting 2 lines of text max. I've tried NSMutableParagraph style to add the ellipses truncation that I want, but with NSMutableParagraph I can only get NSTextView with 1 line and without NSMutableParagraph, I get a scrolling text with as many lines as needed to complete text.

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is my text, I can keep going for many characters")
var para = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
para.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
let globalAttributes = [
  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: para
]
let range = NSRange(location:0, length: attributedString.length)
attributedString.addAttributes(globalAttributes, range: range)
cellView.myTextView!.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedString)
```

I've tried height constraint on NSTextView. I've tried:

```
cellView.myTextView!.textContainer?.containerSize = NSMakeSize(300, 32)
```

I've tried creating IBOutlet for NSScrollView that NSTextView in within and adjusting its height. No luck with getting both 2 lines and truncation. Any help is greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm just missing a method or setup. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a text **field**? You can set the text field cell's `truncatesLastVisibleLine` property. Also, do you need to allow editing but prevent the user from entering more text than will fit on two lines? For a text *view*, have you set `verticallyResizable` to false? Have you set `maxSize`?

Comment: @KenThomases, yes, I've considered a textfield. I actually have a NSTextField for another property on this view. TextField only displays one line. For the textView, I have tried setting verticallyResizable to false and setting maxSize.

Comment: You can make multi-line text fields.

Comment: Yes, I ran across that and it was easy in iOS, but I'm not finding the right procedure for OSX.

Comment: Also, these fields are not to be editable by user, they are only displaying data pulled from API.

Comment: Just drag a multi-line label from the Object library into the view.

Comment: I was able to solve programmatically with: 
let cell = cellView.myLabel!.cell() as! NSTextFieldCell
    
    cell.wraps              = true
    cell.scrollable         = false

Comment: If you post your suggestion by answering the question instead of with a comment, I will mark it as correct. Thank you for your help @KenThomases

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an `NSTextField` configured as a multi-line label. That means setting its `cell`'s `wraps` property to true and, if desired, its `truncatesLastVisibleLine` to true.

Comment: Also, have to set maximumNumberOfLines.

Answer (score 11):

From 10.11 you can use this

```
yourTextViewObj.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

For NSTextField (aka label) You can just do self.textField.maximumNumberOfLines = 2;

That's it.

Comment: Also, need to cell's wraps property.

Answer (score 0):

Max number of lines is now a property of NSTextField

```
label.maximumNumberOfLines = 1;
```